# Webpart title visible while editing, invisible after

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a pretty strange Sharepoint 2010 problem. I have a webpart, which outputs the content of a list.

The webpart has a title with a styled background.

When I edit the webpart, it looks like it should. It has the nice background color, it shows the text ect. However, when I go to the page where the webpart should be, the webpart title is gone. It is not rendered in the HTML code (and therefore, I guess it's not a styling issue).

This is the rendered HTML while editing the page:

```
<td id="WebPartTitleWPQ6" class="ms-WPHeaderTd" title="Documents">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-WPTitle" style="text-align:justify;">
<a href="link" accesskey="W">
<nobr>
<span>Documents</span>
<span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ6"></span>
</nobr>
</a>
</h3>
</td>
```

And when not editing, this td is never rendered.

The content in the webpart, is shown.

It shouldn't be a security problem, as I've moved the web part around so i've tried different zones. I've also tried different css classes.

Last of all, i've made sure the Chrome isn't none. I've tried all.

Any ideas why the webpart title is not shown?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am having a similar issue, I want some web part titles to appear red and they do, but only when editing, otherwise they all have the default coloring. Mine are still visible though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the stpes given below may be it can solve your problem :

- Open Sharepoint Designer 2010.
- Open the Masterpage in Advanced mode.
- Located the `<title>` tag. It contained an `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` tag.
- Remove any spaces between the `<title>` and `</title>` tags. 
  That means, the title tag started and ended in the same line.
- Save and Publish.

Let me know the outcome.

Thanks

Comment: Can someone add some clarity to this? I'm not sure what they mean exactly, can't seem to find a <title> tag in oslo.master, seattle.master, or v4.master in SharePoint Designer 2013.